# Dynamically creating files to the Watch Extension on runtime

Tags: ios, mapkit, watchkit, watchos

In my iOS application I am creating images with MKSnapshotter during its runtime. I would like to show these images on the watch but I don't know how to dynamically make them reside in the Extension folder.

Is it possible to dynamically add files to the Watch Extension? If so, which path should I use for saving these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You main app has no access to the Watch Extension folder and sandbox, because those are 2 different apps (from iOS/WatchOS point of view). You should initiate [WCSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession) and send raw image data (bytes) to the Watch with a message.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I am generating an image and then scheduling a notification. I want that image to be shown as an attachment. Is there anyway for me to see this image in the notification if I don't already have the image in the extension folder?

Comment: Would it be possible to send raw image data to the watch even if the watch app isn't in the foreground or the background?